# System Properties from JNLP file in static code block

Tags: java, jnlp

Overview:

- I want my Java Web Start application to be secure, so I'm signing the JNLP file
- When signing the JNLP file I cannot set configuration System Properties directly, so I pass them into the `main` method as arguments
- The arguments do not get set as System Properties in time to be used by a `static` code block

---

Details:

I have a series of Java Web Start (JNLP) applications that were written years ago. There are some values set within the JNLP file that need to change depending on environment (like database connection string). Previously we were using the Property element of the JNLP file to set those values to System Properties directly.

With newer versions of Java, we want to sign the JNLP file to make it more secure. Since I need to allow configuration, I am using a JNLP template to allow changes without re-building the jar. JNLP templates do not permit the Property element to be wildcarded, so I've moved the configuration values to the Argument section. In the `main` method of my application, I am parsing the arguments and setting them to System Properties.

However, some of the setup for the application (i.e. checking the database connection) occurs in `static` blocks. Code in `static` blocks is executed before the `main` method is executed, so the `static` blocks are now running before my System Properties are set.

Is there a way to get values from the JNLP file to the System Properties in time to be used by static code blocks? If not, do I need to choose between signing the JNLP files or re-architecting the applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better off re-architecting the application to get the configuration information from a separate properties file / object.

As you observed, injecting stuff into the System properties object early enough can be tricky.  The problem is doing it before the static initialization of dependent classes happens.

If you do want to keep trying the system properties approach, here's a plan that might work.

Refactor your "main" class into two parts.

```
public class Launcher {

     public void main(String[] args) {
         // Extract properties from args
         // Set them in System Properties object
         // Use class.forName(...) to load the RealMain class
         // Use reflection to call RealMain.main, passing the args.
    }
}

import ...
public class RealMain {
    // real stuff
    public void main(String[] args) {
        // real stuff
    }
}
```

The assumption is that the `Launcher` class has no static class dependencies on the `RealMain` class, or *any other class* that might trigger premature static initialization.

Comment: Brilliant! The refactor worked really well. I'm going to stick with that approach to reduce the impact on our sys admin team and their deployment process. Thanks!